# Insert Into table from access form

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Command134_Click()

    Dim strInsert As String
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    strInsert = "INSERT INTO [SEMP Documentation] (Staff_Name) VALUES " & (Staff_Name.Value) & ");"
    MsgBox (strInsert)

    Debug.Print staffname
    db.Execute staffname, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

Staff_Name is a combo box on a Microsoft Access form that has the name of 10 or so individuals, each with their own index.

The message box has the Staff_Name.Value call producing the index rather than the actual text name. For reference, the values in the combo box are pulled from a table, where the first column is the staff's index and the second column is the staff's name.

The user picks which person they are.

Secondly, the db.Execute statement fails; the table name is SEMP documentation that I am trying to insert into - "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table "

any help appeciated

Comment: why do you have a spaced table name?

Comment: I changed it and still problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 "INSERT INTO [SEMP Documentation] (Staff_Name) VALUES ('" & (Staff_Name.Value) & "');"
```

2nd prob is

`db.Execute staffname, dbFailOnError`

should be  `db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError`

Comment: what's the 2nd prob?

Comment: The problem is I have the following code (changed what's posted here)
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Documentation] (Staff_Name) VALUES (MyName);"
CurrentDb().Execute (strSQL)

Comment: and access is saying that I do not have enough parameters on the execute statement

Comment: hi maST - I did that, and still received the issue of "expecting" different amount of arguments. After some digging around, I noticed that it was responding to the amount of arguments that I put in the values part of the query string. Still don't know how to fix it, but I'm looking into it being part of the execute statement or SQL syntax